# Convert plain text into a template literal in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, filesystems, fs

Hope everyone doing great.

Actually, I'm trying to build an email automation tool where a user can send an email to multiple recipients and I want to implement such a functionality where the user can write email body in a text file e.g **Hello ${name}, how are you ${name}** and the program simply read body from this text file and replace **${name}** with the **names of the recipients** that comes from .csv file.

**Problem**: The problem I face here is instead of replacing ${name} with names it simply sends the exact text read from the file for example Instead of Hello John, How are you it sends Hello ${name}, How are you. So, Is there any way to convert plain text into JS template literal or any other way to do this task? It would be a great help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: No code no help. Please complete the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If possible you should provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [`vm`](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) module:

```js
import vm from 'vm';

const context = {
  name: 'Jane',
};
vm.createContext(context);

const templateFileContent = 'Hello ${name}, how are you ${name}';
const interpolatedString = vm.runInContext(`\`${templateFileContent}\``, context);

console.log(interpolatedString);
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, It works completely fine for me 